Salesforce error trying to Launch a Quick Action from Aura Component
I am trying use a Quick Action that launches a Flow and I'm getting the error

The action you specified isn’t available on the current record page.

Here is the Component Code:
    <aura:component
        implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
        <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
        <lightning:quickActionAPI aura:id="quickActionAPI" />
        <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
        <aura:handler name="refreshPage" event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.forceRefresh}" />
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
        <aura:attribute name="case" type="Object" />
        <aura:attribute name="caseRecord" type="Case" default="{'sObjectType': 'Case'}" /> 
        <force:recordData aura:Id="recordData" recordId="{!v.recordId}" mode="EDIT" targetRecord="{!v.case}"
        targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}" recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"
        fields="ID, OwnerId"/>
<div>
<lightning:button variant="brand" class="paylocity-orange" label="Tax Direct Request" 
                        onclick="{!c.TaxDirectRequestClick}"/>
</div>

Here is the Controller code:
TaxDirectRequestClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    debugger;
    var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
    var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var fields = { recordId : recId};
    var args = {actionName: "Case.Escalation_Request",
                entityName : "Case",
                targetFields : fields };
    actionAPI.selectAction(args).then(function(result){
        actionAPI.invokeAction(args);
    }).catch(function(e){
        if(e.errors){
            //If the specified action isn't found on the page, show an error message in the my component
            console.log(e.errors);
        }
    });

The Escalation_Request quick Action Launches a Flow that accepts the Case ID in a variable named recordId
